# PDF changes color when viewed in a browser - from wordpress site

Tags: pdf, colors

I have a wordpress site running version: 5.8.1. I am using the Stackable blocks- card block to display a cover photo of the pdf and a link to the resource. I have uploaded a pdf that has a blue background and blue texts. When i click the link in the card to view the PDf it brings you to a copy of the pdf but it's colors have changed to red.

this happens on at least two resources.

Anyone else run into this.[image]

[[image: original][1]]

Comment: i can view the original fine with a browser but when i view the same file hosted on WP it shifted red

Comment: here is the red version https://messagingconvention.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/BasicTipsSpanish.pdf

Comment: I just had a look at the internals of the Spanish file - some printing oriented colorspaces, graphics states with alpha-is-shape and overprint usage combined with transparency... To draw that PDF correctly, you need a really good PDF processor, and even then the output remains device dependent.